# No routes matched path

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Hi there I'm trying to create an admin panel for my project,
I have this code where I render the front end for the user, and for the admins

```
<div className="App">
  <Router>
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/admin-panel' exact  element={<BackEnd/>} />
    </Routes>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<FrontEnd />}></Route>
    </Routes>
  </Router>
</div>
```

On my BackEnd Component I have this code

```
 <div>
        <Header />
        <div className='panel'>
            <SideBar />
            <Routes>
                <Route path='admin-panel/add-product/' element={<AddProduct/>} />
            </Routes>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So I want to create, when ever I click on my sidebar list, to render my pages, for this example my AddProduct View,

THanks a lot;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Backend` is rendering nested sub-routes then the parent path needs to specify that it can match nested routes. Use the `*` wildcard.

```
<div className="App">
  <Router>
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/admin-panel/*' element={<BackEnd/>} />
      <Route path="/" element={<FrontEnd />} />
    </Routes>
  </Router>
</div>
```